# JS array remove side by side duplicate strings

Tags: javascript

I have array, for example:

```
var arr = ['ab', 'cd', 'cd', 'ef', 'cd'];
```

Now I want to remove duplicates which is side by side, in this example it's at index 1 & 2 (cd).

result must be:

```
var arr = ['ab', 'cd', 'ef', 'cd'];
```

I tried this code but it's not working:

```
var uniqueNames = [];
$.each(arr, function(i, el){
    if($.inArray(el, uniqueNames) === -1) uniqueNames.push(el);
});
```

but this filters unique and I don't want this.

Comment: What happens in case of `['ab', 'cd', 'cd', 'cd', 'ef', 'cd']`..?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could check the successor and filter the array.

```js
var array = ['ab', 'cd', 'cd', 'ef', 'cd'],
    result = array.filter((a, i, aa) => a !== aa[i + 1]);
    
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 2):

One way of doing this

```js
var arr = ['ab', 'cd', 'cd', 'ef', 'cd'];
var uniqueNames = [];
$.each(arr, function(i, el){
    if(el != uniqueNames[i-1]) uniqueNames.push(el);
});
console.log(uniqueNames);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 2):

A simple reverse loop - splicing out the neighbour duplicates. For when you don't mind mutating the original array. When `splice` is used the length of the array obviously decreases which is why it's easier to work from the end of the array to the beginning.

```js
let arr = ['ab', 'cd', 'cd', 'ef', 'cd'];

for (let i = arr.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
  if (arr[i-1] === arr[i]) arr.splice(i, 1);
}

console.log(arr);
```

Answer (score 2):

Simply iterate the array, keeping track of the last element.

```js
var data = ["ab", "cd", "cd", "ef", "cd"];
var result = [data[0]];
var last = data[0];
for (var i = 1, len = data.length; i < len; i++) {
  if (data[i] !== last) {
    result.push(data[i]);
    last = data[i];
  }
}
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 2):

```
let uniqueNames = [];
let arr = ['ab', 'cd', 'cd', 'ef', 'cd'];

arr.forEach((element) => {
   if(element !== uniqueNames.slice(-1).pop()) {
      uniqueNames.push(element);
   }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Short `String.replace()` approach with extended example:

```js
var arr = ['ab', 'cd', 'cd', 'cd', 'ef', 'ef', 'cd', 'cd'],
    result = arr.join(',').replace(/(\S+)(,\1)+/g, '$1').split(',');
 
console.log(result);
```

Comment: @JamesThorpe, all extra cases should be mentioned beforehand. It works for the current input. The separator can be changed and it's not a problem